# Do IntelliJ modules have anything to do with Java 9 modules?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, java-9, java-module

In IntelliJ there is something called module. Is it in any way related to Java 9 modules (Project Jigsaw)?

Comment: See [IDEA modules vs Java modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#modules-idea-java).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these are not related unless you start treating a module of IntelliJ to be a JPMS module as well, i.e. including a `module-info.java` under the source directory of the module.

This is when there should ideally be a one-to-one mapping between them.